# How to make an image black and white in opencv c++?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, java-native-interface

Actually I'm a complete beginner in `opencv` and in `native C++` concepts so please excuse me if my question is so simple. Basically I want to convert an image to `Black&White` by using `native C++` for that I tried to find tutorials but I couldn't find any. **Thus can anyone please help me to learn this concept ?**

Comment: it is good to start by reading the [tutorials](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d9/df8/tutorial_root.html) and docs from opencv, the function you are looking for is this one: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor and "black&white" most probably is greyscale... if not it is a binary image which you can achieve with threshold :)

Comment: @api55 thanks a lot for your time and answer

Comment: Why do you need OpenCV, JNI and C++, if a you have a bitmap in Android and want to convert it to b&w?

Comment: @AlexCohn because I want to learn C++ part of `OpenCV`

Answer (score 2):

```
cv::Mat colorMat, grayscaleMat, binaryMat;
```

First convert to grayscale:

```
cv::cvtColor(colorMat, grayscaleMat, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

Then apply a binary threshold to the grayscale  image:

```
cv::threshold(grayscaleMat, binaryMat, 100, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
```

Also, you may want to consider using the [OpenCV4Android SDK](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html) .

Answer (score 1):

You should use the cvtColor function.
Lets say 'image' is your original photo, and 'gray_image' is the variable where you will store your new gray photo:

```
cvtColor( image, gray_image, CV_BGR2GRAY );
```

('image' & 'gray_image' are 'Mat' type)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and answer but could you please elaborate the java and c++ part as well means how to pass the bitmap to the `native C++`

Comment: @anonymous not sure what you ,meant by "java and c++". Are you trying to make an android app?